# Build styleguide colors from SCSS

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I'm building a living styleguide and would like to automatically generate the color information from our `colors.scss` file. My goal is to make maintaining the color list as easy and simple as possible. My current setup is this:

```
$colors: (
//  Variable     Name          Color       Hover    Description
    white:      'White'       #ffffff     #CCCCCC   'Use this for page background and text color on dark elements',
    black:      'Black'       #000000     #333333
);
```

In another file:

```
@function color($label) {
  $color: map-get($colors,$label);

  @if $color{
    @return nth($color, 2);
  }

  @warn 'No specified color for "#{$label}"; add your own to colors.scss';
  @return null;
}

.color-values-data {
  font-family: sassToJs($colors);
}
```

I pass the data to JavaScript using [sass-to-js](https://github.com/malyw/sass-to-js) and plan to build the color chart with that information. I can use the colors in my stylesheets like this:

```
.heading {
  color: color(white);
}
```

Is there some way I could simplify or otherwise improve this? For instance, I'd prefer using `$white` instead of `color(white)` but I believe that would require an additional compilation step before SCSS since it doesn't support dynamic variable names.

This project is not using any existing styleguide engine because it needs to generate a UI module for the CMS we're using (Magnolia) and this approach allows us to use the exact same components in the styleguide as the actual site itself.

Answer (score 0):

You may just use SCSS variables, as you see here http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2
That's it.